# Showing Maps in Iphone's native map application from my app in iOS 6

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode4.5, ios6-maps

i want to display the maps in iphones map application. so, when i tap on map button it should navigate to iphone app. i have the code that works fine in other than ios 6 . but i want it in ios 6.thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple documents its maps URL scheme [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/MapLinks.html). You must replace `maps.google.com` with `maps.apple.com.`

Comment: Should consider old iOS. You cannot use maps.apple.com on iOS 5 and earlier. Try  i([[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >=6)

Comment: @XiaochenDu Yes you are right, the question is regarding ios 6